# Duplicate records

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a problem regarding duplicate record.I have a table called tbl_Kisiler as shown below.

```
 ID     Adi
 ---   ----
 1     harun
 2     ahmet
 3     melis
 2     ali
```

I have a ListBox like upper table.My question is:I want to move a new inside ListBox those duplicate ID records in C#.How can I do that?

---

```
ID,      Adi,     
----      ----      
1        harun
3        melis
2        ali
```

Cheers,

Comment: uhm.. can you rephrase your question? I don't quite understand it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to create a new listbox containing records with duplicate ids, i.e.

```
ID    Adi
---  ----
2    harun
2    ali
```

If that is what you want to do, you can use linq to select the duplicates

```
var duplicateIDs = from r in records
                   group r by r.id into g
                   where g.Count() > 1
                   select g.Key;

var duplicateRecords = from r in records
                       where duplicateIDs.Contains(r.id)
                       select r;

var nonDuplicateRecords = from r in records
                          where !duplicateIDs.Contains(r.id)
                          select r;

listBox2.DataSource = duplicateRecords.ToList();
listBox1.DataSource = nonDuplicateRecords.ToList();
```

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question.  I'm fairly sure the linq queries could be improved, hopefully someone can suggest an more fluent way of doing it.

Comment: @DoctorMick-First of all,thanks for your reply.After to select duplicate ids,I want to move to  a new listbox.How can I do that?

Comment: @Selo - I've updated my answer, should do what you want now I think.

Comment: Thanks so much.I want to ask a last question.Just the opposite,How do I make a listbox containing records without duplicate ids?I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the duplicate item from the DataTable before binding it to the ListBox

Have a look at the link below for removing the duplicate item

[How to imporove the performance of my method created to remove duplicates from a DataView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856632/how-to-imporove-the-performance-of-my-method-created-to-remove-duplicates-from-a/6856707#6856707)